# В чем смысл sudo -n?

Tags: shell, sudo

Читаю `man sudo`:

```
-n      The -n (non-interactive) option prevents sudo from prompting the user for a password.  If a password is required for
        the command to run, sudo will display an error message and exit.
```

Насколько я понимаю, с флагом `-n` пароль запрашиваться не будет, но если какая-то из выполняемых команд потребует прав суперпользователя, то выполнение завершится с ошибкой.

В чём смысл такой команды? Как это можно использовать?

Может, суть в наличии и валидности timestamp'a, который позволяет некоторое время не повторять ввод пароля?

```
➜  sudo ls # ввожу пароль
Password:
a.txt   b.txt

➜  sudo -n ls # работает timestamp, пароль не спрашивает
a.txt   b.txt

➜  sudo -k # инвалидация timestamp

➜  sudo -n ls
sudo: a password is required
```

Но это просто искусственный пример. А на практике чем это может быть полезно?

Comment: может быть смысл в автоматизации некоторых процессов? А то запустят скрипт, а он зависнет и будет ждать пока кто-то введет пароль. Но у нас же автоматизированный скрипт, значит вводить пароль будет некому и скрипт зависнет на неопределенное время. А таким образом мы можем поймать ошибку и своевременно отреагировать

Comment: @BOPOH: Интересная идея. А в автоматизированном скрипте как мы вообще можем надеяться, что sudo не потребует пароля?

Comment: а кроме паролей нет способов аутентификации? :-)

Comment: @DmitryV.: я не знаю способа передать в `sudo` ключ ssh вместо пароля.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ключ нельзя, а [kerberos токен](http://serverfault.com/questions/578755/how-can-i-force-sudo-to-accept-a-users-ad-password-on-rhel6) можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен для автоматизации, при наличии других неинтерактивных способов  аутентификации PAM (лдап например), чтоб в случае если sudo фоллбекнется до парольного PAM не случилось интерактивщины и скрипт не завис

Comment: @NickVolynkin, еще можно сделать [sudo без пароля](http://askubuntu.com/q/147241) (хотя и не нужно)